# How to use the posts_join filter hook to join the posts table with another table

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to use the wordpress `posts_join` filter with my `$args` - see below:

`clicked_activities_array` holds post IDs and I am able to return back the title in the `foreach` loop but need to order it based on the ID's in the history table.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array( 'cme-education', 'post', 'media_gallery', 'learning-zone' ),
'post__in' => $clicked_activities_array,
'posts_per_page' => '13',
'post_status' => 'publish',
);
                    
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $p) :
  echo $p->post_title . "<br /><br />";
endforeach;
```

The above code get's the posts but I want to be able to join this table using the `posts_join` hook to another table called `history` on `activity_id` (the post id) and `ID` on the `wp_posts` table. I am stuck on how to do this, so any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you joining?

Comment: the history table